# Как сделать поиск похожих товаров из бд? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я получаю из строки поиска значение запроса и делаю поиск по бд.

```
items = Items.objects.all()
Items.objects.filter(name=request.GET.get('search', ''))
```

Если товар присутствует в базе данных, то он выводится. Например: White EliteBook Tablet 810
Однако если вписать White Elitebook, то выводит пустое значение.
Как сделать поиск похожих товаров из бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SQL есть оператор сравнения `LIKE`, который помогает искать частично в строке.
В Django этот запрос реализуется следующим образом:

```
result = Items.objects.filter(name__contains='White Elitebook')
```

Comment: а ещё есть индексы полнотекстового поиска)